# Majority element of JPEG images using Divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

You have an array A with n JPEG images some of which are identical.

You can check if two objects are equal but you cannot compare them in any other way—i.e. you can check A[i] == A[j] and A[i] != A[j], but comparisons such as A[i] < A[j] are not meaningful.

The array A is said to have a majority element if strictly more than half of its elements are equal to each other.

Use divide and conquer to come up with an O(n logn ) algorithm to determine if A has a majority element.

................................................................................

My solution:
I have done this problem by dividing the array of images into halves until there are arrays of size 1 or 2 .

If the array is of size one then we return the element present in that array and if it is of size two then we compare between the elements of the array. If they are same then we return that element otherwise it does not return.

As we move recursively up the tree we do the same operations on the returned elements until there is only one returned element.

It would be easier for me to explain with an example

Suppose the array is ABABAABA

STEP 1 We divide into halves

[ABAB][AABA] -> [AB][AB][AA][BA]

Now, [AB] returns nothing (since A is different from B)

```
 [AB] returns nothing

 [AA] returns A

 [BA] returns nothing
```

Thus the only returned element is A which is the majority element.
Now, my problem is that you will find the above algo will not work for many arrays  such as AAAAABBB but I think this is not working only because of the ordering of A's and B's shuffling of the array would make the problem gone. Please tell me am I correct?

And if my algo is totally wrong then please give a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28960878/3308055