# How to Write Recursive Majority Element Algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I just wrote the iterative algorithm to find the majority element and it works as intended. However I wanted to know how I would write this version Recursively for both functions: majorityElement() and find()

```
bool majorityElement(const int arr[], int& majority, int size) {
    //majority == -1 

    int count = 0; //count the number of occurrences
    int* array = new int[size]; //receives arr[]
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = arr[i];

    //finds a Candidate and set the majority element
    find(array, majority, size); 

    //counts the number of occurrences of the majority element
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == majority)
            count++;
    }

    delete[] array;
    //return true if majority element occurrence is greater than array size/2
    return count > (size / 2);
}


bool find(int array[], int& candidate, int sz) {
    int index = 0; //index for the majority element
    int count = 1; // count the occurrences;

    //traverse array 
    for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
        if (array[index] == array[i])
            count++;
        else
            count--;
       
        if (count == 0) {
            index = i;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    //setting the candidate majority element
  return candidate = array[index];

}
```

Comment: Which programming language is this? Please [edit] your question and add the according laguage tag. And please make a [mre], not only code fragments.

Comment: I am not sure which problem you try to solve but especially `find` looks very dubious. Are you sure it works as intended?

Comment: This question was [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957303/divide-and-conquer-algorithm-for-finding-the-majority-element).